# Group array of Swift dates by month

Tags: swift, nsdate, nscalendar

I have an array of Swift dates:

```
[date1, date2, date3, ..., dateN]
```

I want to group these dates by month:

```
[
    [date1, date2],
    [date3],
    ...
    [dateN],
]
```

All days of a month should be inside the same month array.

How can I group an array of dates by month, either functionally or imperatively?

Comment: I did not know about the init with grouping matt thanks. Handy to know

Comment: key problem is how to express the month grouping

Comment: @netshark1000, Use this :- Dictionary(grouping: dateArray) {$0.month}, hope this helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Swift 4**

This is how I would have done it:

```
extension Date {
    
    var month: Int {
        return Calendar.current.component(.month, from: self)
    }
    
}

// some random arbitrary dates
let rawDates = [Date(), Date().addingTimeInterval(100000.0), Date().addingTimeInterval(100000000.0)]
// the desired format
var sortedDatesByMonth: [[Date]] = []

// a filter to filter months by a given integer, you could also pull rawDates out of the equation here, to make it pure functional
let filterDatesByMonth = { month in rawDates.filter { $0.month == month } }
// loop through the months in a calendar and for every month filter the dates and append them to the array
(1...12).forEach { sortedDatesByMonth.append(filterDatesByMonth($0)) }
```

Tested and working in a **Xcode 9.2** playground.

*Output*

`[[], [], [2018-03-21 12:29:10 +0000, 2018-03-22 16:15:50 +0000], [], [2021-05-21 22:15:50 +0000], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]`

**Usage for hypothetical AppointmentObject**

```
extension Date {
    
    var month: Int {
        return Calendar.current.component(.month, from: self)
    }
    
}

// some random arbitrary dates
let appointments = [AppointmentObject(), AppointmentObject(), AppointmentObject()]
// the desired format
var sortedAppointmentsByFromMonth: [[AppointmentObject]] = []

// a filter to filter months by a given integer, you could also pull rawDates out of the equation here, to make it pure functional
let filterFromDatesByMonth = { month in appointments.filter { $0.from.month == month } }
// loop through the months in a calendar and for every month filter the dates and append them to the array
(1...12).forEach { sortedAppointmentsByFromMonth.append(filterFromDatesByMonth($0)) }
```

**Alternative**

Not a direct answer to your question, but maybe a viable solution to your problem too. Many people, righteously, pointed out the existence of the `Dictionary` class. Using the above mentioned `Date` extension, you could also do this:

```
Dictionary(grouping: rawDates) {$0.month}
```

*Output*

Your keys are now the month indicators (5 being may and 3 march)

`[5: [2021-05-21 22:46:44 +0000], 3: [2018-03-21 13:00:04 +0000, 2018-03-22 16:46:44 +0000]]`

Comment: Thank you! My problem is a bit more complicated. The date object (from) is part of an AppointmentObject. I need AppointmentObjects grouped by month. let filterAppointmentsByMonth = { appointment  in appointments.filter { $0.from.month == appointment.from.month } } gives an error (ambiguous reference)